# jQuery Authenicated Jenkins APIS Call

Tags: ajax, json, jenkins

I'm having issues making an authenticated Jenkins API call - I'm trying to retrieve some JSON data. I'm using it on a webpage with jQuery - anyone with Jenkins experience, any ideas?

Note: the password is the user API key from Jenkins.

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://jenkinsurl/build3/testReport/api/json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  username: "jenkinsusername",
  password: "1axxxxsdasde3ad8",
  success: function (){
    alert('To test it worked'); 
  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what is actually going wrong. That URL looks suspicious. First, try querying the url in your browser to verify you get something back. Then, try playing with the ajax call in your browser's web developer console.

Comment: The URL is fine - I just changed it to the above for example purposes. i've tried in a browser and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing something similar; ran into all sorts of issues.  Documentation is scanty on this sort of thing.  But finally got it working, at least on my Jenkins.  There's a possibility that the following won't work with every Jenkins authentication plugin; I've only tested against the built-in authentication and the scripted authentication.

To authenticate, do the following in your java script:

```
    $.ajax(jenkins_relative_url + 'j_acegi_security_check', {
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    async: true,
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    data: {"j_username": username, "j_password": password},
});
```

The ajax call above would get cookies loaded up that Jenkins uses to determine if you are authenticated.  After that, you could do the same $.ajax calls you where making, but without the username and password parameters.  You should only need to authenticate once, then make any number of calls against Jenkins - as long as you carry around those cookies.

Comment: Thanks however no luck as of yet. Using that j_acegi_security_check url, in my browser takes my to a login error page. Is it possible to actually check my Jenkins setup can use this?

Comment: In my case, I'm using the stand-alone Jenkins running on Windows; not behind Tomcat.  That may have something to do with it.